# Realm (kotlin): querying objects that have list of children where at least one child has non-null field

Tags: kotlin, realm

I have following models

```
    @RealmClass
    open class Sport (@PrimaryKey open var sportId: Long = 0,
          //...
          open var events: RealmList<Event> = RealmList(),
    ) : RealmObject()

    @RealmClass
    open class Event(
        @PrimaryKey var id: Long = 0L,
        //...
        open var defaultGame: Game? = null
    ) : RealmObject()
```

and following query

```
    fun getSports(): RealmResults<Sport> = realm.where(Sport::class.java)
            .isNotNull("events.defaultGame")
            .distinct("sportId")
            .sort(orderSportFields, orderSport)
            .findAll()
```

When I call `getSports()` function, I receive:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal Argument: isNotNull() by nested query for link field is not supported.
```

How to change my query to get the list of sports where each sport has at least one event with `defaultGame` field being not null?

Thanks!

Comment: If this app is not in production yet, a nice trick you can do is add a `defaultGameId` field that is a String, because `isNotNull` would be supported for a String. Then when `defaultGame` is set, also set `defaultGameId` value.

Comment: App is not in production yet and I like the trick. It's not "cleanest" solution, but clean enough. Thanks!